# Android memory usage: How much is too much?

Tags: android, performance, memory, memory-management, profiling

I am currently working on an app with some large amounts of legacy code, some of which was written 10 years ago. The app itself is not finance/banking 150 modules giant, it's fairly average application with about 10-15 screens for 3D instructions, but even in idle state it consumes up to **200 - 250 Mb of RAM**, even before the 3D model showing part! It sounds like **a lot**, but I just don't have enough experience in app profiling to explain this situation to the business.
Is this just "a problem" or "Avengers Level Threat"? How much memory average application should consume, and how much would be too much? I understand it depends on app specifics, but it would be great to just have general understanding of how things should be.

[image: An example of app memory consuming]

Here is an example of memory usage - app just showing paginated list of entities at this moment, nothing special.

Comment: May I know how much **TOTAL** ram do you have in your system ?

Comment: i think this is quite a lot, but realistically there might not be too much you can do about this, if you avoid memory leaks and use best practices as far as you can then i suppose this is just the minimum requirement of your app, but i have some doubts if this is really the total amount you need

Comment: but, i don't think you're going to find an answer on SO unfortunately, most likely this is going to get closed as opinion based if i had to guess

Comment: @a_local_nobody, well some opinions is what I want to hear to be honest, so it is not a problem

Comment: it's a problem for stack overflow, as questions asking for opinions will get closed, those aren't allowed here